# How can I capture the desired group using REGEX

Tags: regex

How can I break this string, to just capture Chocolate cake & nuts?

Input string

pizza & coke > sweets > Chocolate cake & nuts >

I am using this regex:

```
.*[\>]\s(.*)
```

However, it is capturing Chocolate cake & nuts >
How can I remove the > and the space in the end?

Desired result
lastone=Chocolate cake & nuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding capture of space around the final phrase is a bit tricky.  In Java,

```
.*>\s*(\S+(?:\s+[^>\s]+)*)\s*>.*
```

captures everything except initial and ending whitespace between the final two `>`'s.  Note that you only get the last stuff between `>`'s because the `*` is "greedy."  It matches the longest possible string that allows the rest of the regex to match.

Note that when you ask about a regex, you need to specify which regex engine you're using.

**Edit: How it works**

`.*>` matches anything followed by `>`. Then `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace chars, and capturing starts. The `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters, and `(?:\s+[^>\s]+)*` matches 0 or more repeats of spaces followed by characters that are anything except `>` and space (this is the tricky part), whereupon capturing stops. The `(?: )` form of parentheses are non-capturing. They only group what's inside so `*` can match 0 or more of whatever that is. Finally, `\s*>.*` matches a final `>` preceded by optional whitespace and followed by anything.

Comment: Thanks Gene. I am not using any language. I am checking the string using regex coach. Your solution works perfectly. Can you please explain your solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regex coach is Perl-compatible. That's what you need to state. @Meow

Comment: Thanks a ton Gene, I am learning regex. Just for my practice, if I am interested in capturing sweets, how can I improve and make my regex general  .*[\>]\s(([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)).* in some cases i might have input such as sweets > Chocolate cake & nuts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try move the `>` out of `()`. `.*[\>]\s(.*?)\s*>`

Or the more precise version `[>\s]+(\w+[\w ]*&[ \w]*\w+)[> ]+`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jH3jE6/3)